# Обновление div из php без перегрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, html

Хочу сделать простенький чат. Примерно должно работать так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $("#div_comments").load("chat.php"); 
});
function show_chat() {
   $("#div_comments").load("chat.php");
   }; 
</script>

<div id="div_comments">
<!-- тут выводятся сообщения -->
</div>
<form method='post' action="chat.php">
   <input id='username' name='username' type='text' placeholder='Ваше имя'>
   <input id='message' name='message' type='text' placeholder='Сообщение'>
   <button id='submit' name='submit' type='submit' onClick="show_chat(); return false;" />
<form>
```

**chat.php** (схематично)

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];     //  получаем данные из формы
mysql = "INSERT name, message";   //  пишем их в базу
$comments = mysql ("SELECT * ");  //  читаем из базы всё что есть
echo '<p>'.$comments.'</p>';      //  выводим
```

Я пробовал разные вариации, уже запутался. Не удавалось добиться, чтобы php работал. Если там просто написать

```
<p>message</p>
```

тогда оно отрисовывается. А если

```
<?php
echo 'message';
?>
```

тогда ничего нет. А кнопка отправки так вообще не работает. Поправьте, пожалуйста.

**Добавил после Ваших комментариев:**

Создал два файла в корне пустого сайта:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_chat(btn) {
   $("#div_comments").load("chat.php", $(btn).closest("form").serialize());
}
</script>
<h>ЧАТ</h>
  <div id="div_comments">
<!-- тут выводятся сообщения -->
</div>
<form>
   <input id='username' name='username' type='text' placeholder='Ваше имя'>
   <input id='message' name='message' type='text' placeholder='Сообщение'>
   <button id='submit' name='submit' type='button' onclick='show_chat(btn)'>Click<button>
</form>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['username'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
echo '<p>'.$name.'</p>'; 
echo '<p>'.$message.'</p>'; 
?>
```

Кнопка нажимается, параметры в адресной строке появляются, поля ввода очищаются и на этом всё.

**Igor**, насчет работы с базой данных, спасибо, я это всё умею, просто не хотел загромождать код здесь, написал же "схематично". Да оно пока и неважно.

Comment: `chat.php (схематично)` Пока в вашем вопросе оно схематично - мы врятли чем либо поможем, пока что у вас там схема психбольницы видится.

Comment: я всего лишь не стал расписывать доступ к базе данных и ввод/вывод строк из неё. В принципе, там достаточно оставить единственную строку:   echo 'message';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
function show_chat(btn) {
  var data = $(btn).closest("form").serialize();
  console.log("show_chat", data);
  $("#div_comments").load("chat.php", data, function(response, status, xhr) {
    console.log("complete", response, status, xhr);
  });
}

<button id='submit' name='submit' type='button' onclick="show_chat(this)">Click</button>

$name = $_GET['username'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

---

```
mysql = "INSERT name, message";   //  пишем их в базу
```

Вы все-таки почитайте, как "писать в базу" хоть что-нибудь.

```
$comments = mysql ("SELECT * ");  //  читаем из базы всё что есть
```

... и как читать - тоже.

---

Давайте разбираться. Вы говорите:

> Кнопка нажимается, параметры в адресной строке появляются, поля ввода
>   очищаются и на этом всё.

То, что Вы описываете, соответствует сабмиту формы и перезагрузке страницы. Хотя с `type='button'` этого происходить не должно. На странице есть еще формы?

У меня был еще пропущен слэш в закрывающем тэге кнопки.

Comment: дописал комментарий прямо в вопросе, ибо тут код выводится нечитабельно.

Comment: @СтаршийДоктор прошу прощения, поправьте - `onclick="show_chat(this)"`

Comment: не, не хохочет (

Comment: Это весь код на пустой странице, внутри тегов body. Слеш поставил, теперь на кнопку не реагирует. Пробовал с другого браузера, мало ли. Так же. А правильно ли, что тег <form> я оставил пустым?

Comment: @СтаршийДоктор `form` без атрибутов - нормально. Добавьте вызовы `console.log` (как в ответе) и посмотрите, что выводится в консоль браузера.

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: пробовал с разных браузеров. Залил на другой хостинг. Ошибка та же.

Comment: Погуглил, добавил, заработало. Спасибо. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>